# How to define a `DependencyProperty` for a collection type in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create a `DependencyObject` which is created from Xaml.
It has a  `DependencyProperty` of type `List<object>` defined like so:

```
    public List<object> Map
    {
        get { return (List<object>)GetValue(MapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Map.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Map", typeof(List<object>), typeof(MyConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Xaml:

```
        <MyConverter x:Key="myConverter">
            <MyConverter.Map>
                <TextPair First="App.Blank" Second ="App.BlankViewModel"/>
            </MyConverter.Map>
        </MyConverter>
```

I keep receiving `Cannot add instance of type 'UwpApp.Xaml.TextPair' to a collection of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Object>`. 
What can cause this error? Thank you.

Comment: The cause of this error is simple: You defined the `Property` of type `List<object>` and set a value of type `TextPair` which is not the correct type.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, i tried your suggetion, but it still fails.

Comment: I am confused because I made no suggestion. So what do you tried?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg, you pointed out, that collection has wrong type and i changed it to 'List<TextItem>

Comment: Did you define your `myConverter` inside `Resources`?

Comment: @Justin XL, yes, it's inside Application.Resources

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the type of your `DependencyProperty` with `typeof(List<object>)`. This means the property requires exactly this type. Since `List<object>` is not 
a `TextPair` we need to be more generic. Instead of using a special generic list type just use `IList` as type and add `new List<object>()` as default value. This should solve your problem.

```
public IList Map
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(MapProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MapProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Map", typeof(IList),
        typeof(MyConverter), new PropertyMetadata(new List<object>()));
```

**EDIT:**
Looks like UWP behaves a bit different than WPF. To run this code in UWP you need to use the generic `IList<object>` instead of `IList` as property type.

Comment: This is it. Also if you put `[ContentProperty(Name = nameof(Map))]` on your `MyConverter` class, you can remove `<MyConverter.Map>` from your xaml.

Comment: I'm getting ` XamlCompiler error WMC0015: Cannot assign 'TextPair' into property 'Map', type must be assignable to 'IList'`

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko try changing `IList` to `IList<object>`.

Comment: Strange, UWP behaves different than WPF in this case. I've editet my solution. Thanks for the hint @JustinXL

Comment: If you use this method you are going to get an unintentional Singleton: one instance of List<object> shared between all instances of MyConverter.

Answer (score 2):

Using the method shown by Fruchtzwerg you will get an unintentional singleton: one instance of List shared between all instances of MyCoverter.

See [Collection-Type DependencyProperties in the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties).

To avoid this, you need to set the value separately, like this

```
public class MyConverter
{
    public IList Map
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(MapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MapProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Map", typeof(IList),
        typeof(MyConverter), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyConverter 
    {
        // SetValue causes DependencyProperty precedence issue so bindings 
        // will not work. 
        // WPF supports SetCurrentValue() which solves this but UWP does not 
        this.SetValue(MapProperty, new List<object>());
    }
}
```

However, this will cause another problem due to [DependencyProperty Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence): you will no longer be able to bind to MapProperty as you have used SetValue which has a higher precedence.

So the best & correct solution is to use a [CreateDefaultValueCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.createdefaultvaluecallback). You can do this as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Map", typeof(IList),
    typeof(MyConverter), PropertyMetadata.Create(
    new CreateDefaultValueCallback(() =>
    {
        return new List<object>();
    }
}));
```